# How to have style applied for wpf datagrid row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I am Having requirement on WPF Datagrid row,Whenever user selects a DatagridRow,corresponding datagrid Cells borders should have thickness of 1 or 2 .

or Provide margin for textboxes/Textblocks within in DatagridCell.

With regards,
Mahens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but here's an example of modifying the default listboxitem style for a gridview (NOTE the top level Grid is the top-level element in a xaml file):

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="itemstyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListView Name="grid" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemstyle}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

I just created a generic Person type with a Name string property and an int Age property.  I added a few of these to a list and set the ItemsSource of grid to the List.

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for Help.But im looking for wpf datagrid row,Upon selecting wpf datagrid row,corresponding cells in that row should get bordered with different colour or different thickness

Comment: I see.  I think you'd have to use something like a datatemplateselector for the celltemplateselector of the individual cells you want to modify.  i was playing around with it and couldn't get the selector to fire off of a selection change, so you might need to do something about that.  ill try to look into it more when i get some time.